# How can I make hyperref with "bookmarksnumbered=true" number the parts in conjunction with classicthesis?

Tags: hyperref, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis. If I pass `bookmarksnumbered=true` to `hyperref`, everything but the parts is numbered nicely in the PDF bookmarks.

However, I would like to see the parts numbered in the same way as in the table of contents.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,titlepage]{scrbook}

\usepackage[eulermath,eulerchapternumbers,parts,floatperchapter]{classicthesis}

\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true} % <==

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{mypart1}
\chapter{mychapter1}
\chapter{mychapter2}
\part{mypart2}
\chapter{mychapter3}
\chapter{mychapter4}
\part{mypart3}

\end{document}
```

which produces the output below. But I would like to see the

> I mypart1
>
> II mypart2

in the bookmarks.

[image: Red: Not what I want]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `hyperref` command `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\thepart{\Roman{part}}}` in your preamble. There's a line in classicthesis.sty that otherwise sets this to nothing.

Comment: Did this work in the MWE for you? I tried it before and after `hypersetup` but nothing changed in the bookmarks. My texmf dir says that I use `classicthesis 2015/09/06 v4.2`.

Comment: You're right. It only works with the changes introduced in https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src/d41b5e123ab2d723ce660e2a11229fc9cceac272/?at=MayPI